# Keras backend: argmax if above threshold, else -1

Tags: keras

I would like to create a custom accuracy function that uses `argmax` for `y_pred` only if the value at `argmax` exceeds a threshold, else -1.

In terms of the Keras backed, it would be a modification of `sparse_categorical_accuracy`:

```
return backend.cast(
    backend.equal(
        backend.flatten(y_true),
        backend.cast(backend.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1),
                     backend.floatx())),
    backend.floatx())
```

So, instead of:

```
backend.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)
```

I need a function with the pseudocode logic:

```
argmax_values = backend.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)
argmax_values if y_pred[argmax_values] > threshold else -1
```

As a concrete example, if:

```
x = [[0.75, 0.25], [0.85, 0.15], [0.5, 0.5], [0.95, 0.05]]
```

and `threshold=0.8`, then the result of the desired function would be:

```
[-1, 0, -1, 0]
```

How can I achieve this using the Keras backend? My Keras version is `2.2.4`, so I do not have access to the TensorFlow 2 backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `K.switch` to conditionally assign values from two different tensors based on a condition. Using `K.switch`, your desired function would be:

```
from keras import backend as K

def argmax_w_threshold(y_pred, threshold=0.8):
    argmax_values = K.cast(K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1), K.floatx())
    return K.switch(
        K.max(y_pred, axis=-1) > threshold,
        argmax_values, 
        -1. * K.ones_like(argmax_values)
    )
```

Note that both tensor in the `then` and `else` part of the `K.switch` must have the same shape, hence the use of `K.ones_like`.

On your example:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
>>> x = [[0.75, 0.25], [0.85, 0.15], [0.5, 0.5], [0.95, 0.05]]
>>> sess.run(argmax_w_threshold(x))
array([-1.,  0., -1.,  0.], dtype=float32)
```